# What happens if a particle moving in a hollow sphere is given a horizontal velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a heavy particle moves inside a frictionless hollow sphere with radius a.
The particle is
held on the inner surface of the sphere at z = −a/2,  where z is measured upwards from the centre of the sphere. Given a horizontal velocity U. If U squared = 4ag,
find the maximum and minimum height that the particle reaches during the ensuing motion.

There is actually a first question about finding the energy equation of the particle moving in the sphere  depends on h(angular momentum) z(vertical displacement) and vertical velocity.  I managed to solve it. But I have no idea how to solve the one I give.

z = -a/2 means the position vector makes a angle pi/3 with downward vertical. But what happens after the particle is released with a horizontal velocity U? If the particle is given a horizontal velocity, can I still use the former energy equation? Or will it leave the surface and conduct free fall? Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: I think the question is under cylindrical polar coordinates and the energy equation in first question is done in that way

Comment: I've answered the question but also voted to migrate it to physics.SE.

Comment: Well, that will teach me to vote to migrate to physics.SE :-)